# TextSelection in a TextField issue

Tags: dart, flutter, textfield, textselection

After selecting the whole text in a `TextField` using `TextSelection()` it does indeed select the whole text but after pressing a key on the keyboard, it starts adding pressed letters/numbers to the start of the text as opposed to deleting the old one and replacing it with the newly typed letters/numbers.

Is this expected behavior? If so, is there any way I can programatically select the text and then replace it upon pressing a key on the keyboard?

This is how I select the text:

```
manualEditorNode.addListener(() {
  if (manualEditorNode.hasFocus) {
    manualInputController.selection = TextSelection(
        baseOffset: 0, extentOffset: manualInputController.text.length);
  }
});
```

Comment: Id create a bug report. It would be great if you first checked if you can still reproduce in `master` channel.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am currently in the `master` channel. Should I perhaps try the `dev` channel?

Comment: No, if it doesn't work in `master` just create an issue with the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in my program. Maybe you can try something like this?

```
var cursorPos = textInputController.selection;
setState(() {
  textInputController.text = newInput;

  if (cursorPos.start > newInput.length) {
    cursorPos = new TextSelection.fromPosition(
        new TextPosition(offset: newInput.length));
  }
  textInputController.selection = cursorPos;
});
```